# Problema de Eslint no Reactjs com useEffect, nesse caso como faço pra não precisar colocar o // eslint-disable-line

Tags: node.js, react, front-end, react-hooks

Bom pessoal, tenho uma função que ultiza algumas variáveis dentro dela. Porém ela só deve ser executada quando uma dependência em especifico dela for alterada. no caso o state de **index**

```
useEffect(() => {
    setRows([])

    const max = index === pages ? data.length : index * range 

    for (let i = index * range - range; i < max ; i++) {
        setRows(oldElemets => [...oldElemets, data[i]])
    }

}, [index])
```

Comment: E...? Detalhe mais a sua pergunta.

Comment: eu expliquei, acontece que dentro desse useEffect existem varias variaves, porem de fato eu só preciso que essa funcao seja reexecutada quando o index mudar. E o eslint fica dando warning que existem outras variaves dentro da funcao e pede pra adicionar no array de dependencias do useEffect. Porem como eu disse só o que importa é se o index mudou. e queria evitar de usar o comentario // eslint-disable-line pro waring sair.

Answer (score 0):

O objetivo da regra `exhaustive-deps` do linter, é impedir que os hooks leiam propriedades ou estados obsoletos do componente.

Por mais que as demais dependências não mudem durante a renderização, o linter não sabe e não tem como garantir isso.

Como regra geral, todas as variáveis e métodos  precisariam ser declarados dentro do array de dependências para que o linter conseguisse garantir que o efeito vai ser executado sempre utilizando os valores mais recentes dessas variáveis e, deste modo, não ocorreria mais o warning.

Uma alternativa seria utilizar o hook useCallback como suporte, para garantir que sua função sempre receba os dados atualizados (mas ainda assim, todas as variáveis precisariam ser declaradas como dependência):

```js
    import {useCallback} from 'react'
    ... 

    const funcao = useCallback((index) => {
        setRows([])
        const max = index === pages ? data.length : index * range 
        for (let i = index * range - range; i < max ; i++) {
            setRows(oldElements => [...oldElements, data[i]])
        }
    }, [pages, data, range]) // garante que pages, data e range sempre estarão atualizados

    useEffect(() => {
        funcao(index)
    }, [index, funcao]) // garante que index e funcao sempre estarão atualizados
```

Deve-se tomar muito cuidado neste caso, pois a regra `eslint-disable-line` pode ocasionar o não report situações que podem ocasionar comportamentos inesperados na aplicação. O ideal é de alguma forma passar todas as dependências para garantir que o efeito não utilize propriedades ou estados obsoletos.

Comment: O que acontece é que se eu colocar todas as depedências que ele esta pedindo acontece um 'Maximum update depth'.